# Add Android Library into Project using svn:external

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, android-library, svn-externals

Is it possible?

There are three games which use common android lib and situated here - http://server.us/svn/greatlib.

My dream (and my PM's too ;) to "checkout by one click".

Before I have to

1. checkout game ( http://server.us/svn/game1 )
2. checkout lib
3. set lib in properties.

I'm trying improve it.

My way:

I have done some manipulations with SVN:external.

1. added library dir into game project (libraries/greatlib)
2. set svn:external like this "/svn/greatlib/ libraries/greatlib"
3. add "android.library.reference.1=libraries/greatlib" into default.prop.
4. Fail : cannot add android library which is not a project in workspace

Have you any thought about this?

Answer (score 1):

Hearkening back to this great old post:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx

Here is what I envisioned when I saw the ADT 14 preview:

[image: Hopes]

The hope was that since the library projects are being included as jar references via the Library Projects classpath container in Eclipse, that closing the referenced library would not impact the presence of said jar in the classpath container.

Unfortunately,

[image: Dashed]

I don't see how svn trickery will get you past the fundamental issue that is with the ADT plugin itself: you cannot reference library projects that are not open and in the workspace with the Eclipse-based build toolchain.  Might be a totally different story with an Ant build.

That being said, Google made a noble attempt to boost library projects to first class citizens.  Still some work to be done.